# Validate a from when submitting from outside of html submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a form with many different input fields (some of them are not really input but behave as inputs).

When submitting the from from the regular button click each field is validated through angular validation and html - such as required, ng-maxlength, minlength, etc..

Now we want to add a shortcut to submit the form on keyboard click. That code is running from the controller behind the html. How can I check the validity of the form from there? I know I can get the form by `document.forms["myForm"]` but can I use that somehow to check the validity same way as .$valid is working in the html? Could I somehow show the error messages on the html as well?

I tried to add jQuery validation plugin for that but seems like it is too much work to change the entire validation mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get the form with`document.forms["myForm"]`".
It's bad practice to use DOM manipulation inside a controller. 
You can access the form with `$scope.myForm`. But beware of the fact that it will be initialised asynchronously.
But that shouldn't be a problem when you want to access the form after a keyboard click.
When you access the form with `$scope.myForm` you can iterate throw the `$$controls`. In this object are all form fields.
For example you can do it like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.myForm.$$controls, function(value, key) {
    value.$setDirty();
    value.$setTouched();
});
```

And one more reminder when you use angular don't try do use JQuery for everything. If you want to use plugins search for angular plugins